# Track Changes while using nested set model

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy, nested-sets, mysql-5.6

I am considering switching my organizational heiarchy to a nested set model that I gathered from [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). I put it in an [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d81f85/2) to hopefully help visualize it. What is there is simplified, there are/will be more levels, but that should suit to help explain.

In my organization, the coaches change often. There will be on average 2-3 new coaches per team per year, coaches will move up or down in the organization, there is a lot of volatility. Above the coaches, everything will pretty much stay the same but changes can/will occur.

Using our old model (Adjacency List) we are able to track changes via other tables populated by triggers but this new model will have new requirements to track. I see us needing to track the `rgt` and `lft` numbers, as well as date removed and date added. Further, I see some complications in "rebuilding" the tree for any given date or date range.

The two options I have considered are:

First, creating a table to track changes, tracking the `rgt` and `lft` columns as well as date values, then remove the coach/team from the tree. I see this way as having a hard time "rebuilding" for a historical look-up.

Second, leave the "removed" coaches/team in the tree, adding a bool to the tree indicating if the coach/organization is still in use and adding a change table that only tracks the dates and previous parent. This would make historical look-ups easier (I see the date range aspect being difficult), but clutter and bloat the tree.

Which option would be better? Is there an option that I am missing?

We would be using the historical look-up fairly often but for one-off queries, all aggregate data will be compiled and stored the following day by organization level.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't actually clear what tracking and historical lookup you were doing specifically. However I have a general answer for you question.

Nested sets and adjacency list models are not mutually exclusive. That means that you can use both within a table, like with the following schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `node` (
  `node_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `l` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `r` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`node_id`),
  KEY `l` (`l`),
  KEY `r` (`r`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `node_has_node` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
    REFERENCES `node` (`node_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

With this schema it is easy to query subtrees for nodes and  count them with `l` and `r`. At the same time it is easy to write queries dealing with direct ascendant and descendant nodes with `node_id` and `parent_id`.

Thus I suggest you to extend your table with nested sets markup without wiping out parent reference. So you can keep using existing tracking logic, and have advantages of nested sets model.